# HTML5 - History API

Tags: javascript, html, url-routing, html5-history

When looking for a way to change a page without refreshing all the content I found out the history API.

Apparently, it is possible to make a link that change a part of the page and have an impact on the history. For example, this link could send me from myaddress.com to myaddress.com/page.html from this link and only update the subpage.

But how could I get the url myadress.com/page.html go directly to the right page with all the content outside the subpage ?

The following demo (not mine) does the content replacement but not the url routing for example : https://html5demos.com/history/

I would like to avoid URL rewriting and jquery if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would do it if you were using a regular link and no JavaScript in the first place.

Generally that would involve a server side language with a template (so you can avoid duplicating content (like menus) that is shared between pages.

You could just create static HTML files though.

Comment: Do you mean by adding require_once in the subpage for example ? Doesn't that mean that the whole page is reloaded ?

Comment: "Do you mean by adding require_once in the subpage for example? " — that would be one way to include shared content in multiple pages.

Comment: "Doesn't that mean that the whole page is reloaded ?" — No. When you update the page with JS, you should just update the content that is different. You should only load the whole thing if you are loading the page from scratch (i.e. by visiting the URL directly instead of via `pushState`)